# In SQL Server, how do I select NULL for two specific cases (query included)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have this query:

```
SELECT crr.Codes
FROM Client_Response_Ranges_for_SSRS_Respondent_Answer crr
WHERE crr.Name =  @ReportParameter1
```

but I want to say that - if `@ReportParameter1` (which is a parameter I'm using in a SSRS report) is either `All` or `Prescreens`, then override what it usually returns (the `nvarchar` `NULL`) and return a true null instead (i.e don't return anything? ) ..

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT     
   CASE 
      WHEN @ReportParameter1 = 'All' THEN 'NULL'
      WHEN @ReportParameter1 = 'Prescreens' THEN NULL
      ELSE crr.Codes 
   END
```

but it does not work and gives me an error that says:

> *An error occurred during local report processing.
>
>   An error has  occurred during report processing.
>
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet2'.
>
>   The variable name '@ReportParameter1' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.*

Comment: In SQL there is a big difference between not returning anything (no rows) and returning a `null` value for a field. Which would you like?

Comment: Also, 'null' is a char/varchar but null (no quotes) is a `null`

Comment: @JamieF - I'd like to return a null value  , thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed a single quote before null and giving a alsias name for the select  column. Try below:

```
SELECT     CASE when @ReportParameter1 = 'All' then null 
                when @ReportParameter1 = 'Prescreens' then null
                else crr.Codes end as codes
FROM         Client_Response_Ranges_for_SSRS_Respondent_Answer crr
where crr.Name =  @ReportParameter1
```

Comment: Ah I just understood why we need to add the `as codes` part . Hmm,  that's quite subtle!

Comment: have found the sql server error messages and warnings always confusing and the error would be because of some small things like this

Comment: @Adel The `as codes` is needed because SQL needs a label for the column.  Since the value is from a `CASE` it doesn't know what to call it.  You'd think it could figure it out from the `else` clause, but that doesn't work in general, so it doesn't try.  Presumably, you're doing something else with the result of this `SELECT`, which is why it needs the label.

Comment: @gmlobdell Using SSRS is already "doing something else". It needs column names! :)